# Want to work in Qooxdoo. Help me

Tags: javascript, ajax, qooxdoo

I am new to Qooxdoo. I downloaded it. After that i do not know the next step. I want to know how to work in it. I went through http://qooxdoo.org/documentation/1.1#getting_started but am not getting it to work. Please can anyone tell me how it should work? What steps should I take?

When i execute the **create-application.py** in cmd, i get a wordfile which is **Create application**.

how should i run the application. when i type **cd C:/custom
generate.py source-all** in cmd it says error as **'generate.py' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.** What should i do for this.

Comment: If you don't understand even Hello World there, then... I suggest you drop this library and choose something else to learn.

Comment: I think you need to provide more details of what is going wrong here, your question is very vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you pasted there are the contents of create-application.py. If you're seeing that, it probably means your system doesn't know how to handle .py files. Make sure Python is installed correctly (entering "python" in a command window should start the interactive Python shell), then try running "python create-application.py".

Comment: Hi sir,
when i type "python" its displaying

ActivePython 2.6.5.14 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.6.5 (r265:79063, Jul  4 2010, 21:05:58) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on
win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> python create-application.py
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    python create-application.py
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 

this is what i get in my cmd sir.